# Profusion of threads on imbalanced data - can we merge/deem canonical any?

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates, meta-faq

We appear to have a number of overlapping threads on imbalanced data. Here are just a few of the more highly-upvoted ones:

[Are unbalanced datasets problematic, and (how) does oversampling (purport to) help?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/357466/are-unbalanced-datasets-problematic-and-how-does-oversampling-purport-to-he)

[When is unbalanced data really a problem in Machine Learning?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/283170/when-is-unbalanced-data-really-a-problem-in-machine-learning)

[Does an unbalanced sample matter when doing logistic regression?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6067/does-an-unbalanced-sample-matter-when-doing-logistic-regression)

[What is the root cause of the class imbalance problem?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/247871/what-is-the-root-cause-of-the-class-imbalance-problem)

Some of these threads themselves link to and summarise even more questions and answers on the topic (there are 950 questions tagged [unbalanced-classes](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unbalanced-classes), many of them popular). [Stephan Kolassa's heroic effort to summarise and pin down the problem](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/357466/are-unbalanced-datasets-problematic-and-how-does-oversampling-purport-to-he) is probably the most comprehensive *question* on the topic, but there are useful answers strewn across many of these threads.

We still keep getting new questions about this, though, and IMO they often seem to attract misleading/incorrect answers. It would be useful to have a canonical thread to point people to on this, but I don't know enough about the topic to judge which of these could be merged/closed as duplicates/deemed canonical, so I thought I'd ask here. **How can we best simplify this situation?**

Comment: It is possible to close a question as a duplicate of not 1, but up to 5 other questions.  It might be worth starting to close existing questions as dups of the top set.  That will elevate them further.  Then we start closing new Qs as dups.

Comment: A place to start would be to identify one (or a handful) of canonical threads and tag them with [tag:faq].  That enables a quick search whenever you encounter a similar post, streamlining the process of identifying a duplicate and closing the new thread.

Comment: @gung-ReinstateMonica: I think that would be a great way forward. Can only moderators close as a multi-dupe? Or how do mere mortals do that?

Comment: @whuber: great idea. I concur with mkt that the four threads above would be a great place to start. I started adding the FAQ tag to all four, they already all carry the unbalanced-classes one. Question: the "FAQ" tag says it it applied by mods, but I could add it just fine. Should I have been prevented from doing so? If not, perhaps we could revisit the tag excerpt.

Comment: @StephanKolassa, mere mortals can only close a thread as a dup of 1 other thread.  After that, you can leave a comment with links to other dups, &/or you can flag for mods to add the others.

Comment: We cannot enforce the applied-only-by-mods rule.  The intention is to be sparing in our application of the [tag:faq] tag and to monitor it to avoid abuses (such as someone applying it to their own threads or their favorite threads).

Comment: whuber notes that multi-dupe closing is a lot of work for the mods, and proposes to use a single dupe target, where we link to the others. I would suggest we use [When is unbalanced data really a problem in Machine Learning?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/283170/) as a canonical dupe, and edit links to the other threads into that question, at the very top. Thoughts, anyone?

Comment: @StephanKolassa Part of my concern was that no single question seems to have answers that address the topic comprehensively, so the information is diffused. My hope was that those of you who understood the topic better could identify threads that could be merged so that all bases were covered (and then we could designate it canonical). If that's not feasible, I agree with your suggestion.

Comment: @mkt: I see your point. I think that this would be very hard, simply because there are so many variations of the "problem". Some come from using accuracy as a KPI, some don't mention their KPI at all and treat imbalance as a *prima facie* problem without explaining why it isn't. The, ahem, lack of statistical sophistication does not help, either ("but I'm using precision, not accuracy, so [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/312780/1352) is not a duplicate!") I think a comprehensive treatment would be more of a journal paper than a useful CV thread. ...

Comment: ... Does anyone want to write a paper for *The American Statistician* or *Chance*, so we can petition SO to be able to close as duplicates of a journal paper?

Comment: @StephanKolassa Alright, then I agree with your suggested target for a canonical thread, though perhaps we can ask Tim to broaden it a little to include statistics in the title.

Comment: @StephanKolassa I think you are too modest. Your effort to which the OP links approvingly seems to me a good target.

Comment: I just saw [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/316114/247274) answer for the first time, and I didn't see it referenced anywhere in here. // @StephanKolassa It's awfully tempting to write something for *The American Statistician*...

Comment: [And it’s even coming up on the economics Stack…](https://economics.stackexchange.com/q/52528/32979)

Comment: These questions are accumulating a large number of Linked Questions, so that the ones displayed in the right pane are subsetted.  It would be really nice if the ones selected for display were customizable (sorted by votes e.g.).  Barring that SE team solution, I'd suggest cross-referencing them prominently in each question (or maybe linking here?).

Comment: [This](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/603663/247274) seems like a useful link, and the [Wynants article](https://bmcmedicine.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s12916-019-1425-3) seems to cover the high points about predicting probabilities rather than categories. While that is not explicitly about imbalanced classes, predicting probabilities rather than classes tends to come up in that context.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<sup><sub>In the interest of taking a decision, I will post a few answers for you to vote on. Please feel free to post more.</sub></sup>

**Option 1: Do nothing**. First do no harm, etc etc.

Comment: To be clear, this option means that _new_ questions would be closed as duplicate of _one of_ the four (or possibly another), depending on nuances between them as perceived by the close-voters?

Comment: @BenReiniger That's probably the best-case scenario, yes.

Answer (score 0):

<sup><sub>In the interest of taking a decision, I will post a few answers for you to vote on. Please feel free to post more.</sub></sup>

**Option 2: Vote to close threads as duplicate** of [When is unbalanced data really a problem in Machine Learning?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/283170/when-is-unbalanced-data-really-a-problem-in-machine-learning).

*Not just new threads, but also the other threads in the question.

Answer (score 0):

<sup><sub>In the interest of taking a decision, I will post a few answers for you to vote on. Please feel free to post more.</sub></sup>

**Option 3: Vote to close threads as duplicate** of [Are unbalanced datasets problematic, and (how) does oversampling (purport to) help?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/357466/are-unbalanced-datasets-problematic-and-how-does-oversampling-purport-to-he).

*Not just new threads, but also the other threads in the question.

Answer (score 0):

<sup><sub>In the interest of taking a decision, I will post a few answers for you to vote on. Please feel free to post more.</sub></sup>

**Option 4: Vote to close threads as duplicate** of [What is the root cause of the class imbalance problem?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/247871/what-is-the-root-cause-of-the-class-imbalance-problem).

*Not just new threads, but also the other threads in the question.

Answer (score 0):

<sup><sub>In the interest of taking a decision, I will post a few answers for you to vote on. Please feel free to post more.</sub></sup>

**Option 5: Merge some subset of the threads in the question**, and close others as duplicates of this new canonical thread.

If you choose this option, please specify which threads you think should be merged in a comment.

Comment: This has some appeal, but I'm not sure how possible it is to collapse all the nuances into any 1 of those Qs.

Comment: @gung-ReinstateMonica Yes, I am coming around to this view. 3 of the 4 questions I mention cover very similar ground (except for the one about logistic regression) but the difference in framing and detail are quite useful.

Answer (score -4):

<sup><sub>In the interest of taking a decision, I will post a few answers for you to vote on. Please feel free to post more.</sub></sup>

**Option 6: Close new questions as duplicates of all 4 threads in the question**

Note that this seems to be a lot more work for the mods; I think it is best avoided for that reason.